# Scope of Continue Handler in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is scope of ContinueHandler in below scenario?. Is stmt2 covered for exception handling by continue handler?

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR ...;  -- handler H1
    stmt1;
    stmt2;  
  END;
```

Comment: How are you using the `handler`? with a `cursor` or not?

Comment: @Ravinder with cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [Scope Rules for Handlers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/handler-scope.html):

> A handler declared in a [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) block is in scope only for the SQL statements following the handler declarations in the block. If the handler itself raises a condition, it cannot handle that condition, nor can any other handlers declared in the block. In the following example, handlers `H1` and `H2` are in scope for conditions raised by statements ***`stmt1`*** and ***`stmt2`***. But neither `H1` nor `H2` are in scope for conditions raised in the body of `H1` or `H2`.
>
> ```
> BEGIN -- outer block
>   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR ...;  -- handler H1
>   DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR ...;  -- handler H2
>   stmt1;
>   stmt2;
> END;
> ```

Comment: Thanks but, I went through the doc before posting, lets say H2 does not exit in above code `An exception occurs in stmt2, will declare continue handler catch this?`

Comment: @Abhijeet: Yes, the handler remains in scope for both statements.  The documentation elected to illustrate this using `EXIT HANDLER`, but could just as well have done so using `CONTINUE HANDLER`.